# Difference between mean mode imputation and bfill and ffill imputation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, weka, missing-data, categorical-data

My dataset has 5% missing value. It is a categorical dataset , only two attributes are numerical. If I impute missing value with mean and mode method I got accuracy 0.781, recall 0.500 and AUROC 0.756 whereas if I impute missing value with bfill and ffill I got accuracy 0. 785, recall 0.586, AUROC 0.780.

I cannot understand why I am getting good result for bfill and ffill? what does it imply?

What are the other method available for categorical missing value imputaion?

Answer (score 0):

*Global* imputation methods like mean/mode don't take order (like backward/forward fill) in rows or similarity between rows (like nearest neighbor based imputation) into account. Depending on your data these *local* methods can be better by quite a bit.

Comment: Ok. What are the other imputation methods for the mixture of categorical and numerical data. So far, the methods that I have found applicable for numerical data.

Comment: Not a pandas user. If you are using Weka, you could try the [missing-values-imputation](https://github.com/fracpete/missing-values-imputation-weka-package) package.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am not sure what is the meaning of missing value injection?

Comment: Missing value injection is a useful tool for testing imputation methods that you are eg testing or developing ("controlled/repeatable experiments"). Also, it helps you determine what percentage of missing values in a dataset a model can handle before it deteriorates.